# How to delete WooCommerce categories in bulk that only have one product

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I would like to bulk delete WooCommerce product categories that only contain a certain number of products, is there a hook that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this which worked well for me, I moved the extra categories to un-categorized instead of deleting.

```
function woo_cat_list() {
echo "<div style='color:red;'>";
$args = array(
    //'number' => -1,
    'hide_empty' => false
);
$limit = 10;
$uncategorized_category_id = 21;
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$i=0;
foreach( $product_categories as $cat ) {
    if ( $cat->count <=$limit ) {               
            echo "<br />CATEGORY : ".$cat->name."<br /><br />";
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'product_cat'    => $cat->slug
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                global $product;
                echo "<br />======> PRODUCT : ".get_the_title()." (Will move to uncategorized) <br /><br />";
                $id = get_the_id();
                $p = wc_get_product($id);
                $p->set_category_ids([ $uncategorized_category_id ] );
                $p->save(); // uncomment this to save 
            endwhile;               
            wp_reset_query();           
            wp_delete_term( $cat->term_id, 'product_cat' );
        $i++;
    }
}
echo "Total : ".$i; exit;
echo "</div>";
}           
add_shortcode('woo_product_cat_list', 'woo_cat_list');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I believe:

`$args = array(
    'number'     => -1,
    'hide_empty' => false
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
foreach( $product_categories as $cat )  { 
   if ( $cat->count <=1 ) {
     wp_delete_term( $cat->term_id );
   } 
}`